# Difference between Hyperledger certificates during setup and enroll admin using fabric ca client

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have the doubt of the certificates generation and usage.

1. While doing the network setup, for each organization we are creating admin user and additional user certificates.
2. We are mapping the CA certificates and using in cli bash
3. While using fabric client, we are creating a new keystore and creating and enrolling admin for users again.

What is the usage of Admin user we create for peer and organization using crytp-config.yaml file and crytpgen tool?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, in the examples there are three Roles/Users created in the examples.

1. an Admin, this is the admin for a given organization
2. a User, this is an identity used to interact with the peer
3. a PeerAdmin, this is an identity used to interact with the peer with the additional permissions of being able to create a channel, join other peers and installing chaincode

Comment: I dont see anywhere we can create identity type called PeerAdmin, 1. If this is admin administrator where are we using this certificate. 2. If it is identity in fabric-example I'm nowhere seeing the Users certificates used. 3. We can create the certificates using ca-client itllef, then why are we creating in the node level.